# Liferay No Folder Update Mail Notification on Document upload

Tags: email, liferay, document

I'm subscribed to a document folder.

I've setup mail configuration and I receive update emails after some document is edited (e.g. Description change).

When someone add folders or media documents inside my subscribed folder, I don't get any email.

Is this supposed to work as it is?
Any suggestions?

(Liferay 6.2.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is here: https://github.com/brianchandotcom/liferay-portal/pull/15426/files

You have to implement an ext that override liferay-portal / portal-impl / src / com / liferay / portlet / documentlibrary / service / impl / **DLAppHelperLocalServiceImpl.java**

You start from old class and add only necessaries changes (Not the entire file!)

It's the easiest way.